# awk n-gram extracting not correct

Tags: awk, extract

I'm currently working on an awk script which extracts all n-grams from an input file. 
When running my awk script on a file it prints out every n-gram (sorted) with the number of occurrences next to it.
When testing on an input file it prints out the correct order of n-grams. Only the number of occurrences are not correct.
For extracting n-grams I have the following code:

```
$1=$1   
line=tolower($0)
split(line,chars,"")
begin_len=0 
for (i in chars){
    ngram=""
    for (ind=0;ind<n;ind++){
        ngram=ngram""chars[i+ind]
    }
    if(begin_len == 0){ 
        begin_len=length(ngram)
    }
    if(length(ngram) == begin_len){ 
        counter+=1
        freq_tabel[ngram]+=1
    }
}
```

(sort function not included)
I was wondering if there is something wrong in the code. Or are there some aspects which I have overlooked?

The output I should have is the following:

```
35383
1580    n 
1323    en
1081    e 
940     de
839      v
780     er
716      d
713     an
615     t
```

instead, i have the following output:

```
34845
1561   n
1302   en
1067   e
930    de
827     v
772    er
711     d
703    an
609    t
```

As you can see, the n-grams are correct but the number of occurences not.

INPUT FILE: http://cl.ly/202j3r0B1342

Comment: hard to tell without the input-file

Comment: Nice code,  but please don't make us imagine what is happening. Consider editing your post with some sample input data, your required output, and current output that demonstrates the problem. Good luck.

Comment: input file is now available

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer but may help you (assuming n=2).

Did you happen to convert the original file (that seems UTF-8) to latin-1? I got two sets of figures:

```
==> sorted.latin1_in_utf8_locale <==
   1566 n 
   1308 en
   1072 e 
    929 de
    836  v

==> sorted.utf8_in_utf8_locale <==
   1579 n 
   1320 en
   1080 e 
    940 de
    838  v
```

with latin-1 input the figures are closer to yours. with utf-8 to the expected ones.

However, neither matches. Scratching my head.

BTW, I am not sorting the ngrams in the script but outputting in the form suitable for piping them to `sort -rn`. But this should not cause difference, I guess.

```
for (ngram in freq_tabel)
    printf "%7i %s\n", freq_tabel[ngram], ngram
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm in your class, so here's a couple of hints:

- Copy the exact input file (using clone from github, don't do a raw copy)
- Re-read the assignment, you're supposed to get rid of the leading and trailing spaces, and replace all multiple tabs/spaces with one space.

Also, what's the point of the $1 = $1 on top?

Comment: The point of $1 = $1 is solving the problem you describe in 2). And I don't see the point of doing a raw copy when having the opportunity to clone from github ;-) 
Thanks for the hints anyway.

Comment: Does $1 = $1 also get rid of the multiple spaces/tabs within the sentence?